# Use grid to align wrapped form labels and inputs

Tags: html, css

I am using grid layout to align form labels and inputs vertically:

```css
form {
    display: grid;
    width: 10%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;

}

label {
    grid-column: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

input {
    grid-column: 2;      
    margin-left: 0;    

}
```

```html
<form>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text">

    <label>Mileage: </label>
    <input type="number">        

    <label>Track: </label>
    <input type="checkbox"> 
</form>
```

It works, but I want to keep the same layout (and still use grid) when each `<label>` and `<input>` is contained inside a `<div>` like this:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Mileage: </label>
        <input type="number">     
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Track: </label>
        <input type="checkbox"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried dividing the `<form>` and/or each `<div>` in various combinations, but nothing gets me the exact same result.

How can I align the inputs and labels vertically when they are contained in a `<div>`, using grid?

Comment: adding display:contents to div ?

Comment: One imperfect approach (and *not* cross-browser compatible as yet) is to use CSS Subgrid: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e5qdbpkz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More suitable for a table layout than a grid one:

```css
form {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

form>div {
  display: table-row;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Mileage: </label>
    <input type="number">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Track: </label>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</form>
```